# sql replication using remote server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

PI'm trying to do replicate two data bases.

1. DB in LAN network (Publisher)
2. DB in virtual dedicated network (Subscriber)

According to my situation, replicate publisher implemented in my server in LAN network.But subscriber is implementing on a virtual dedicated server. i configured router port to my server machine in LAN network.using sql management studio on virtual server, i connected to the db in LAN network.But when i try to create subscriber using virtual server db i can't access to the publisher.(IN LAN network.) it gives errors as below.

"SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other alternate name are not supported. Specify the actual server name, 'BESTLIFE\BESTLIFECROWN'. (Replication.Utilities)"

Please help me to solve this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say whether you used the GUI or scripts, but somewhere, a call got made to one of the stored procedures (likely sp_addsubscription) with a server name that doesn't match the actual server name. For instance, the error message above says that the server is called BESTLIFE\BESTLIFECROWN. If that's not the name of the server that you put in as hosting the subscriber, it's not going to work. Whether you need to add a DNS alias or whatever, that's the only value that will work for this setup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.i connected to local db using IP address.but i can't connect publisher like that.How can i fix this?.can you explain this."you need to add a DNS alias or whatever ".

Comment: You need some way to resolve the server name to that IP address. So, having whoever admins DNS for your organization add an entry into DNS such that that happens would be the most robust way to do it if it doesn't happen already.